# Sparksession error is about hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My OS is windows 10

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

This code gives me below error

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\Documents\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py
>   in deco(*a, **kw)
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> ~\Documents\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.sessionState. :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error
>   while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.(SharedState.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.(SessionState.scala:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:192)
>     ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

My full code is here

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
import findspark 
findspark.init('C:/Users/asus/Documents/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7') 
import pyspark from pyspark.conf 
import SparkConf sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() 
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Comment: We need the whole error message.

Comment: i have updated @eliasah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted it seems you are a Java developer or maybe you were in a hurry to paste the code. In python, you do not write variables with their types like we do in Java i.e 
**SparkContext sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()**.

Also, starting from Spark version 2.0+, you need to create a SparkSession object which is the entry point to your application. you derive your SparkContext from this object itself. Trying to create another SparkContext **"sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()"** results in errors. This is due to the fact that by design, only a single SparkContext can run in a given single JVM. if a new Context is required you need to stop the previously created SparkContext with **sc.stop()**.

That being said from your stack-trace and code I also think you are testing your app locally and do not have a Hadoop and Hive installation on your local machine which is giving you the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
>   at ...

You can install Hadoop and Hive on your Windows machine and try out the following code snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName('CalculatingGeoDistances') \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```